# How to display specific column data to a label from a database using a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a SQL Server database with a table called `student` and its columns are:

- std_id
- username
- password
- age
- address

The scenario is that the user is already logged in and his/her `username` is saved in a session, while he is navigating a label should show the age of the logged user in a label.

I don't know how to do this, many examples shows how to put data from database to label without using `WHERE` clause or without using a session.

This is my code I used that didn't work from the page that is supposed to show the age.

```
    Dim con As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con").ConnectionString
    Dim mycon As New SqlConnection(con)
    Dim agequery As String

    mycon.Open()

    agequery = "select age from student where username='" + Session("user")
    Dim com As New SqlCommand(agequery, mycon)
    lbl_agecurrent.Text = CStr(com.ExecuteScalar)

    mycon.Close()
```

Comment: Just a minor question, why is the database storing the person's age rather than their date of birth?

Comment: best way is when you pull the data of the logged in user on login time fetch the age of that user also and assing in the session variabel so, every time you don't need to call db for the age.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if this matters, but I usually use square brackets around my Session variables. Also, you forgot an apostrophe to close your agequery statement. So when the SQL statement is executed, it can't find a matching username and therefore returns a null value to your label, meaning that nothing is displayed to your user.

If I understand your specifications correctly, I would write this as follows.

```
string ageQuery = "SELECT age FROM student WHERE username='" + Session["user"] + "'"
string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("con").ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(ageQuery, sqlConnection))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    lbl_agecurrent.Text = (com.ExecuteScalar).ToString();
}
```

If you are looking for more information about this, check out http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection

Comment: Just to note that if the username is one that the user has any control over, your query here is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack. Specifically and relevantly, this one: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @AdrianWragg Haha, touche. I love xkcd.

Comment: For that - and, for having a useful answer, of course - have an upvote!